# Send data as XML, not PDF, to a JSP from form build in Form Builder

Tags: forms, pdf-generation, orbeon

I have used a `workflow-send` button to submit form data in XML format to a JSP file. However, it saves data as a PDF as opposed to XML string.

I know it is PDF because I get `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><url>/xforms-server/dynamic/e9002cb0ce38d116e3037bb622050a36</url>` on sysout in the JSP.

My `properties-local.xml` contains the following entries:

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date"  value="[D]/[M]/[Y]"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.email.attach-pdf" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.alfresco.send-pdf" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.pdf" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.alfresco" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.email" value="false"/>
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*"   value="workflow-send"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.success.method.*.*" value="post"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.detail.send.uri.*.*" value="http://localhost:8080/orbeon/xforms-jsp/idm/idm-customer.jsp"/>
<property as="xs:NMTOKENS" name="oxf.xforms.logging.debug" value="document model submission control event action analysis server html submission-details"/>
```

How can I get the data in XML format instead of a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on the [workflow-send](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button), the PDF is generated if either one of the following properties is true: `oxf.fr.detail.send.pdf`, `oxf.fr.email.attach-pdf`, or `oxf.fr.alfresco.send-pdf`. You don't seem to have any of those properties set to true, so the XML (not the PDF) of the form should be sent to the service you specified. I suspect that you might be using a version of Orbeon Forms that pre-dates the introduction of some of those properties. If you are not on version 3.9, I would suggest you upgrade to 3.9 (or newer). If you are on 3.9 or newer, then please post a comment and we'll try to help.